# Selenium WebdriverTimeoutException although the page is already loaded

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver, selenium-edgedriver

I'm new to Selenium and try to automatically open a website in Full Screen mode.

- The website has a **Login** which is already working with Selenium.
- After the login only one button has to be pressed.

Hereby an `WebdriverTimoutException` is thrown in the second last line.

- The `InnerException` says `NoSuchElementException`.
- But when I open the web console, I can see the button.

```cs
IWebDriver driver = new EdgeDriver(System.IO.Directory.GetParent(System.IO.Directory.GetParent(Environment.CurrentDirectory).ToString()).ToString() + "\\webdriver");

driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(@"http://examplehomepage.com");

driver.FindElement(By.Id("username")).SendKeys("abc");
driver.FindElement(By.Id("password")).SendKeys("password123");
driver.FindElement(By.TagName("button")).Click();

driver.Manage().Window.FullScreen();

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));

IWebElement element = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.TagName("button")));

element.Click();
```

I tried it with:

- Edge (85.0.564.44)
- Chrome (85.0.4183.83)
- Firefox(80.0.1).

Comment: You need to post relevant HTML of the element. You can check if the element present inside any `iframe`?

Comment: After you mentioned it i noticed, that the whole dashboard is in an iframe.

Comment: You need to switch to `iframe` first in order to access the element? `driver.SwitchTo().Frame("frame-id");`

Comment: Using driver.SwitchTo().Frame("frame-id"); did solve my problem. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score -1):

1. You can use sleep to delay the interaction
2. You are using ElementToBeClickable. You should also use ElementToBeVisible and also check whether element is enabled as well from isEnabled function.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer but i already tried both solutions. It didn't work.